# tab usercontrol closing event

Tags: wpf, user-controls

Hi i have a tab load this usercontrol. when i wish to close this tab, i wish to call this cancelbutton_click event to pop up confirmation on closing, if OK, then close, if Cancel, the tab stays.

if i use Unloaded event, it will pop up twice before closing.

```
 private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
              cancelbutton_click(sender,null);
        }
```

Cancel button:

```
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
  MessageBoxResult objResult = MessageBox.Show("\nAre you sure you want to cancel?", "Cancel Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);


            if (objResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    TabItem tabItem = parentWindow.FindTabItemByName(ControlType.BusinessesContractors.ToString(), false);
                    this.parentWindow.mainTabControl.Items.Remove(tabItem);
                    this.parentWindow.statusTextBlock.Text = "Ready";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```

how to resolve this? thanks

Comment: This code looks quite horrible by the way, changing elements from a different window is not something one should need to do often or at all. In fact even having to name elements is something that should not occur often either. And is there really no code in the `catch` block?

Comment: i know it's not the proper way, but it's a quick fix. so if i wanna load different user controls into different tabs, and close tab from user control, what's the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Unloaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) is called when the control is already being removed, it's not an event you want to handle often, just create a button which is supposed to close the tab, handle it's click, check if the user wants to cancel via the dialogue and close the tab if he does not.

Comment: i'm already using cancel button on the user control, but there is still a chance user might click the X on the tab to close it

Comment: You are doing something wrong if there is no confirmation if the user clicks the X and it just closes.